# Mongoose Stream JSON Data

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, stream

Hi I have the following code

```
var mq = DeviceData.find().lean().cursor();
mq.on('data', function(data) {
        //code to write to a stream  
}).on('end', function() {
        //code to write to a stream      
});
```

What should I put in the commented block? I think I should create a wrtie stream. The idea is to send a stream of data to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use directly the `pipe` method as following

```
var mq = DeviceData.find().lean().cursor().pipe(yourWritableStream);
```

or from my recipes

```
DeviceData.find({})
    .lean()
    .cursor()
    .pipe(new Writable({
      objectMode: true,
      write(data, encoding, next) {
        // do something with your data
        // call next
    }))
    .on('finish', () => {
      // you can do something when the stream ends
    })
```

Comment: cant or can? typo?